# Правильно ли составлено данное предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Единственный ущерб который должен совершать каждый, это мышечный

Comment: А какой смысл сюда вложен?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

1. Слово "ущерб" не употребляется во множественном числе, поэтому "единственный" в сочетании с ним выглядит неестественно; правильнее говорить о *видах ущерба*.
2. Судя по виду ущерба (мышечный), он направлен на себя. Правильно сказать "*причини(я)ть* себе ущерб".
3. Спорным выглядит утверждение, что "каждый *должен* (причинять себе ущерб)", пусть и с оговорками.

Предлагаемый вариант.

> Единственный вид ущерба, который (всякому) допустимо причинить себе, -
>   это мышечный.

Comment: огромный респект радной

Comment: Кто эта радная, которой респект?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение нужно отредактировать, например, так:

**Единственный "вред" (урон, ущерб), который необходим каждому, – это мышечный.**

Или: **Единственный "вред" (урон, ущерб), который необходимо причинять себе, – это мышечный "вред".**

**Кавычки** могут показать, что речь идет про "полезный вред".

Пояснение

Возможно, автор имел в виду следующее.

**Почему болят мышцы после тренировки?**http://zozhnik.ru/pochemu-bolyat-myshcy-posle-trenirovki/

Во время тренировок происходят микроразрывы мышц, по сути, **при серьезных нагрузках вы наносите себе микротравмы.** Чаще всего тело реагирует на эти разрывы болью...**Собственно, заживление мышечных волокон после таких травм и обеспечивает рост силы и объема.** Происходит активный выброс гормонов и синтез белка, который является строительным материалом для мышц. В результате таких восстановительных процессов **мускулатура увеличивает свой вес и объем**.

Comment: Мысль ясна, но выражена коряво.

Comment: Думаю, авторский вариант просто невозможно "довести до ума". Урон и ущерб имеют отрицательную конотацию (причинение вреда). Тренировки же полезны.

Comment: Урон здесь именно полезный, автор старается таким способом обозначить суть процесса наращивания мышц. Это интересная и привлекающая внимание своей необычностью трактовка, честно говоря, для меня совершенно новая, может быть, и для других тоже.  Информация касается не только спортсменов, но и  всех людей.  Мышцы - это основа нашего здоровья, они помогают сердцу прокачивать кровь. Кстати, в предыдущем ответе авторский смысл не сохранен. А если коряво сказано, то исправляйте.

Comment: Я предложил свой вариант ответа (см.)

Answer (score 0):

Не надо пугать людей непонятным мышечным ущербом/уроном. Это воспринимается как вредное (а возможно, даже непоправимое) воздействие на мышцы. Излагайте свою мысль так, чтобы она была понятна каждому. Как вариант:

**Единственный вид травм, который каждый человек должен себе наносить — это (полезные)  микроразрывы мышц во время тренировок.**

Comment: Как очевидно, нам предложили отредактировать машинный перевод текста, то есть сохранить его содержание и придать ему  грамотную литературную форму. Задача осложняется тем, что мы не знаем контекста, поэтому все попытки  "додумать"  содержание  и предложить свой вариант не имеют смысла.  Мы правим не автора, а машинную речь. А чтобы вносить изменения в содержание, надо иметь оригинал полного текста, а также  быть хорошим переводчиком.

Comment: Ну если это машинный перевод текста, то нужно сказать, что в последнее время авторы ворпросов устраивают нам игры на догадливость.